# Create error if MySQL case statement encounters unexpected value

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query to analyze some data that comes from survey responses and maps user input to an integer column that can be null if the survey respondent did not answer the question. The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
(CASE
    WHEN some_user_text = 'Yes' THEN 1
    WHEN some_user_text = 'No' THEN 0
    WHEN some_user_text = 'Unknown' THEN NULL
    WHEN some_user_text IS NULL THEN NULL END)
FROM survey_data_table
```

I hoped that if I did not provide an `ELSE` clause then MySQL would error out in some way so I could know that my query needed to be adjusted to handle more cases. It seems MySQL actually just returns `NULL` in those cases.

I've thought of doing `ELSE 'asdf'` so that it tries to insert a string into the `tinyint` field. That seems like it will "work" but it feels like a hack. It also means that for a `varchar` field I need the `ELSE 'foo'` to be a string longer than the allowed limit which feels like an ugly hack.

I've thought of writing a lot more code to just ensure that the values in the column match the expected set, but...that's a lot more code to write and maintain.

Is there an easy and good way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you  write a WHERE clause to identify Rows you don't handle, like `some_user_Text NOT IN ('Yes‘,'No','Unknown')` then you have a query that gives you all the data you don't handle, so you can improve the handling

Comment: @CaiusJard your proposal sounds like writing another query (and the code to run it) in addition to the query I'm already writing. Is that right? I'm hoping it's possible to identify rows with uncovered data without writing a second query.

Comment: Does a front end app consume the output of this query?

Comment: Can you make your column NOT NULL (and use -1 / empty string when they didn't answer the question)? Personally I wouldn't try to build in ways for my app to crash, if I was expecting a situation I'd handle it another way, like querying for these erroneous values as a dedicated exercise, or finding a way to show them in the output (set the number bull but have another column of the value - when both are null it means the question was unanswered , when the number is null but the text is not it means that text value is not decoded

Comment: Incidentally you shouldn't build this into a case when, because it can get massive AND it's a code change to handle more values. Instead put the `sone_user_text` into a table along with the value, and left join them

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
--pseudo code, I don't guarantee this is MySQL syntax for creating a table and inserting 3 rows 
Create table surveydecode(answertext varchar(1000), mapvalue int);
insert into surveydecode values(('yes', 1),('no',0),('unknown',null));

SELECT
  mapvalue,
  CASE WHEN sd.answertext IS NULL THEN sa.some_user_text AS undecodedvalue
FROM
  surveyanswers sa
  LEFT JOIN
  surveydecode sd
  ON
    sa.some_user_text = sd.answertext
```

Now with this:

- a null in both columns means the user responded Unknown
- a null in mapvalue and a string 'Maybe' in undecodedvalue means Maybe is not a mapped value
- values can be mapped without code changes (`insert into surveydecode values ('maybe',2)`)
- your app experiences no crashes
- if you want a crash(I really would avoid this), make the destination column that mappedvalue is inserted into a NOT NULL and have a known value like -1 fit unknown ("unknown" is a "known unknown" so why not give it a value? Null can be used for unknown unknowns)
- the output of this query can be inserted into another table. If you want previous inserts to not be repeated, improve the query so it filters out "already dealt with" rows, by including the destination table in the query and right join the survey answers table in, have a where clause that demands the pk of the answers table (the left side of the join) be null to show only rows that are in surveyanswers but not in destinationtable
- If you want to clearly see unmapped values, consider ordering the column so all the non null `undecodedvalue` are at the top/bottom